# How does Google Script send an email when it detects changes in the background, like cron?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet with a script that checks a local library catalog to see if an ISBN-searched book has shown up or not. There's no API or RSS feature so I'm using UrlFetchApp to screen scrape for certain unique phrases that appear in the HTML source for a given book status.

Right now my spreadsheet only updates the "Status" column (which invokes the script based on an ISBN field) when I open the spreadsheet. Is there a way I can have Google Script run my main function and then trigger for changes? The documentation I've read has only mentioned user edits, which is not what I'm looking for.

```
    function ISBNsearch(ISBN){ 
var consortURL = "http://LIBRARYURL/search~S6/?searchtype=i&searcharg=" + ISBN + "&searchscope=4";
var retrieveURL = UrlFetchApp.fetch(consortURL).getContentText();
var searchURLno = retrieveURL.search("BROWSE SCREEN TABLE");
var searchURLyes = retrieveURL.search("Item Location");
var searchURLordered = retrieveURL.search("copy ordered for");

  if (searchURLno > -1){
    var answer = "Not found"
    } else if (searchURLyes > "-1") { 
      answer = "in Consort" 
    } else if (searchURLordered > "-1") {
      answer = "on order" 
    } else if ((searchURLno == "-1") && (searchURLyes == "-1") && (searchURLordered == "-1")) {
      answer = "no input"; }
  return answer;
}

function testScript(){
var response = ISBNsearch("9782711802036");
Logger.log("The answer is " + response);
  return response;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Time Driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#TimeTriggers) to schedule function executions.

You can also [programmatically manage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/managing_triggers_programmatically) these triggers.